# Use of AND or OR with the maximum of a list of things

Tags: grammar, and-or

Which is correct:

> I will pay you the maximum of $10 OR 10% of sales

or

> I will pay you the maximum of $10 AND 10% of sales

Thanks!

Comment: I will pay you whichever is greater, $10 OR 10% of sales.

Comment: The second is ambiguous.  While any reasonable person would take it to mean the same as the first, there are a lot of unreasonable people about.

Comment: Actually both are ambiguous. If the maximum payment is $10, "the maximum of $10" essentially means $10.

Answer (score 1):

> I will pay you the maximum of $10 **and** 10% of sales.

“The maximum of X *and* Y” is correct.

Consider that *maximum* is just Latin for *greatest*—you’re referring to whichever item in this set of things (joined with *and*) happens to be greatest—“the greatest of X, Y, and Z”. In fact, you could just as easily say:

> I will pay you the **greater** of $10 **and** 10% of sales.

The fact that “the maximum of…” is in a subordinate clause makes it easy to misread the sentence in a nonsensical way:

> I will pay you the maximum of $10, **and** [I will pay you] 10% of sales.

Where “the maximum” seems to refer to something implicit, like “the maximum fee”. To avoid this and be more explicit, it might be better to rephrase:

> I will pay you **whichever is greater:** $10 **or** 10% of sales.

Comment: A perfectly reasonable interpretation of "I will pay you the maximum of $10 and 10% of sales"  = You will give me $10, and you will give me 10% of sales, and that is the maximum amount allowed.